# prevent beta gems from being installed with gemfile constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

in a gemfile, with the following gem constraint:

`gem 'testgem', '>= 1.2.0'`

is it possible to prevent a gem `'1.2.6-beta'` from being installed without changing the constrant?

Comment: `>=` condition is dangerous in general and brings the issues like yours. Use `~> 1.2` instead. This won’t install betas and won’t install the next major release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `gem 'testgem', '~>1.2.0'` or `gem 'testgem', '1.2.0'`

using `~>1.2.0` will only use the latest version from the 1.2.x series and not `2.0`

for more info https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic_version_constraint

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide some more information on that, e.g. what `~>` means (or link to the appropriate documentation section)

Answer (score -1):

[Bundler doesn't include pre-release versions in the version check](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/6077) so you don't have to worry about this.